# Extract variables from array and display into view

Tags: php, templates

I wrote this code to load some views. I want to extract the array data passed from the database query to a view and then display it. I've tried with the `ob_start()` and with the `extract()` functions but it seems that is not working. I think the problem is with the controller code of my app but I can't figure how to fix it.Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Model class:

```php
<?php

define( 'STORAGE_PATH', __DIR__ );

class CredentialsManager{
  private $data;
  private $input;
  private $open;
  private $decode;
  private $encode;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->db = new PDO('sqlite:'.STORAGE_PATH.'/clients.db');
  }

  public function save(array $data){
    if( isset( $data ) && is_array( $data ) ){
      $data = [
        $_POST['client_name'],
        $_POST['hosting_provider'],
        $_POST['client_domain'],
        $_POST['username'],
        $_POST['password'],
        $_POST['ftp_host'],
        $_POST['mysql_username'],
        $_POST['mysql_password'],
        $_POST['mysql_host'],
        $_POST['wordpress_user'],
        $_POST['wordpress_password']
      ];

      $stmt = $this->db->prepare( "INSERT INTO clients_details (client_name,hosting_provider,client_domain,username,password,ftp_host,mysql_username,mysql_password,mysql_host,wordpress_user,wordpress_password) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)" );
      return $stmt->execute( $data );

    }
  }

  public function search(string $data){
    if( isset( $data ) && is_string( $data ) ){
      $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM clients_details WHERE client_name = ?");
      $stmt->execute( array($data) );
      $result = $stmt->fetchAll( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
      if( $result > 0 ){
      return json_encode($result);
      }
    }
  }

}

?>
```

View.php class:

```php
<?php

class View{
  private $data;

  public function __construct(){

  }

  public function search(){
    require_once 'search.php';
  }

  public function searchResults(array $results_set){
    ob_start();
    extract( $results_set );
    require_once 'search-results.php';
    return ob_get_clean();
  }

}
?>
```

search-results.php template file:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row-justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $client_name; ?>" placeholder="Cliente">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $client_domain; ?>" placeholder="Dominio">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $hosting_provider; ?>" placeholder="Hosting provider">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" placeholder="Password">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-8">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $ftp_host; ?>" placeholder="FTP Host">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $mysql_host; ?>" placeholder="MySql host">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $mysql_username; ?>" placeholder="MySql username">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $mysql_password; ?>" placeholder="MySql password">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $wordpress_user; ?>" placeholder="Wordpress username">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $wordpress_password; ?>" placeholder="Wordpress password">
        </div>
      </div>  
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and this is the rest of the code that manage the route to the controller and output data from db:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Controller Class
 */
class Controller{
  private $view;
  private $data;

  public function __construct(){
    $this->view = new View;
    $this->model = new CredentialsManager;
  }

  public function index(){
    return $this->view->index();
  }

  public function search(){
    return $this->view->search();
  }

  public function processData(string $request_method, $data){
    if( $request_method === 'POST' ){
      return $this->model->save($_POST);
    }
    elseif( $request_method === 'GET' ){
      $search_results = $this->model->search($data);
      $results_set = json_decode($search_results, true);
      return $this->view->searchResults($results_set);
    }
  }

}

$controller = new Controller;

if( isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) ){
  $requested_uri = parse_url( $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'], PHP_URL_PATH);
    if( $requested_uri === '' ){
      echo $controller->index();
    }
    elseif( $requested_uri != '' ){
      $method = ltrim( $requested_uri, '/');
      echo @$controller->$method();
    }
}

if( isset($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) ){
  switch( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ){
    case 'POST':
      echo $controller->processData('POST', $_POST);
      break;
    case 'GET':
      $q = parse_url( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_QUERY );
      $search_term = ltrim( $q, 'q=');
      echo $controller->processData('GET', $search_term);
      break;
  }
}

?>

PS: I need also to improve the route system, for now is a very dirt solution,it works well, but it will try to manage also the request for the templates page resources and this is not what I want.
```

Comment: Can you also include the contents of search-results.php  ?

Comment: @programmer-man the template it's already included inside the question

Comment: Did you try to send a shorter string from searchResults() just to test that it actually gets called?

Comment: What do you mean? I've not tried, this because I can obtain a json response from the db and for now if I don't fix the route system, this view will be always loaded, so I think it's called

Comment: But you just said: "I've tried with the ob_start() and with the extract() functions but it seems that is not working."

Comment: Yes, if you look at the code, the template is required inside the `ob_start()` and `ob_get_clean()`. The `extract()` is called inside this block, this is why i doubt that it's working

Comment: Is this a typo? require_once 'search-results.php';
Your filename is: search-result.php

Comment: yes, it's a typo, the file name is search-results.php

Comment: What is the output of var_dump($results_set) ? Please show it in the above also.

Comment: It will show the data from the database table, so it's not a problem of data fetching. I've already tested it a couple of times to debug if it was a database problem.

Comment: I understand that it contains data already. I'm curious at the "structure" of the actual result set. It might not be compatible with your view. That's a possible reason.

Comment: What do you mean with "It might not be compatible with your view"? It's sound strange, because every variable is the name of the key inside the data array returned from the database

Comment: Because when I tried it, your view was outputted. My $results_set contained something like this: ["client_name" => "the client_name", "client_domain" => "the client_domain"]. I think yours contains something like [["client_name" => "the client_name", "client_domain" => "the client_domain"], ["client_name" => "the client_name", "client_domain" => "the client_domain"]]. So, your view only supports a single row, not an array of rows.

Comment: Any suggestion to fix this?Consider that the db output is converted into json and then reconverted into array

Comment: Can you show the contents of $results_set ? So that I will know the exact structure of the data.

Comment: `array(1) { [0]=> array(12) { ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["client_name"]=> string(1) "A" ["hosting_provider"]=> string(1) "C" ["client_domain"]=> string(1) "B" ["username"]=> string(1) "D" ["password"]=> string(1) "E" ["ftp_host"]=> string(1) "F" ["mysql_username"]=> string(1) "H" ["mysql_password"]=> string(1) "I" ["mysql_host"]=> string(1) "G" ["wordpress_user"]=> string(1) "L" ["wordpress_password"]=> string(1) "M" } }`

Comment: NB: this is the result output from PDO::FETCH_ASSOC

Comment: See my answer below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit View.php:

```
<?php

    class View{
      private $data;

      public function __construct(){

      }

      public function search(){
        require_once 'search.php';
      }

      public function searchResults(array $results_set){
        ob_start();
        require_once 'search-results.php';
        return ob_get_clean();
      }

    }
?>
```

Edit search-results.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row-justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
        <?php foreach($results_set as $row) { ?>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['client_name']; ?>" placeholder="Cliente">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['client_domain']; ?>" placeholder="Dominio">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['hosting_provider']; ?>" placeholder="Hosting provider">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>" placeholder="Username">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['password']; ?>" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-8">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['ftp_host']; ?>" placeholder="FTP Host">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['mysql_host']; ?>" placeholder="MySql host">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['mysql_username']; ?>" placeholder="MySql username">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['mysql_password']; ?>" placeholder="MySql password">
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['wordpress_user']; ?>" placeholder="Wordpress username">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['wordpress_password']; ?>" placeholder="Wordpress password">
            </div>
          </div>
        <?php } ?>          
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, so I need to loop the passed data? I was thinking that it wasn't necessary due to the php extract function. I've fixed the issue for now by using ajax, but I will try your suggestion and I'll let you know

Comment: You need to loop because $results_set contains an array of clients.